# Axapta 3.0 - X++ Conversion

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm looking to do an operation in AX 3.0, and I'm neither familiar with this older X++ nor can I find comprehensive documentation.

I need to:

- Get the **number of seconds** between **January 1st, 2000** and **today**, and return it as an integer.

Now, how the heck do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date dThen  = 1\1\2000;
date dNow   = systemDateGet();

return (dNow - dThen) * 24 * 60 * 60 + timeNow();
```

There could be a macro for 24 * 60 * 60 in Axapta 3.0, I don't remember.